# How to add a model admin to another app section in Django admin?

Tags: django, admin

I am trying to create a site profile since there is no easy way to add attribute to the existing site models, but I would like the profile admin sits inside the Sites section.

Is there an easy way to add an model admin to another app section in Django admin? I would imagine something like below:

```
class SiteProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Meta:
        section = 'Sites'
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that you are looking for [InlineModelAdmins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

an example could be:

```
class PermissionInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Permission
  extra = 1

class ContentTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name', 'app_label', 'model',)
  search_fields = ['name', 'permission__name']
  inlines = [PermissionInline,]
```

This will render something like the next picture (sorry about the picture, is in spanish)

[image: Picture]

The first 3 fields are for the model `ContentType` and the others fields are for `Permission` Model.

Them, you register the model `ContentType` with `ContenTypeAdmin`

```
admin.site.register(ContenType, ContentTypeAdmin)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think this is what I am looking for. Thanks.